Gnome-extensions list command doesn’t work when called from service
It seems that gnome-extensions list works fine when called just from the terminal and lists extensions. But when it is called from service, it doesn’t.
Script (1):
#! /bin/bash
gnome-extensions list > /tmp/log

Systemd unit file /etc/systemd/system/rot13.service:
[Unit]
Description=ROT13 demo service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=1

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ibse/main.sh # path to the script (1)
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Then I run the service sudo systemctl start rot13 and /tmp/log file, where gnome-extensions list command was redirected, is created, but empty.
When I run gnome-extensions list from the terminal it lists:
example@gjs.guide
ext1@ext.com
ext2@ext.com

I tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland

most likely it makes dbus calls which unsuccessful because lack of X11 DISPLAY

I use wayland, no X11

Do I need to add DISPLAY env variable somehow? @yvs2014

if there's no real correspondent session DISPLAY, I suppose it'll fail with another error. Probably it can be done with binding to graphical target and session, but .. I'd choose some other way not so systemd complicated.
